# what's difference between sql_log_bin and log_bin in MySQL？

Tags: mysql, replication

[image]

can anybody tell me what is the difference between them ?

Comment: I don't know what ` log_bin ` is logging but ` sql_log_bin ` control whether logging to the binary log is done (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-sql-log-bin.html)

Comment: Take a look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: But to answer the question (a quick Google sufficed) see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_log_bin)

Answer (score 6):

`log_bin` is a global variable that is set at runtime. It determines if binary logging should take place, and (if set) the basename of the binary logs. It cannot be changed without restarting the database.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin

`sql_log_bin` is a global **OR** session variable that can be set after the server is running. It's main use is as a SESSION variable to prevent statements from the current session being written to the binary log. Use as a GLOBAL variable is not recomended.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_log_bin

Answer (score 1):

In a Master-Slave setup, both will be on.

But, if you need to do some 'temporary' queries for which `TEMPORARY TABLEs` and/or `binlog-ignore-...` don't suffice, turn off the *session* variable `sql_log_bin`.  If you scratchpad stuff eventually needs replicating, be sure to use `ROW BASED REPLICATION`.

Example...  I had a large ETL process.  I loaded lots of data into a `MEMORY` tables, massaged the data, then put the results into the "real" tables.  The `CREATE`, `LOAD`, and massaging did not need to be replicated, but the `INSERTs` into the real table did need replicating.

That way, I kept the heavy processing only on the Master.

I chose to put the extra tables in a separate database and use `binlog-ignore-db=...`; it seemed cleaner.